# How to know if a String only contains 0 to 9 and no other characters

Tags: java

I am new here and I have a problem with a code.

I have a String of 5 characters, and this is what I've come up with

```
public static boolean isNumber(String strng) {
    return (strng.contains("[0-9]+"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String strng; 
     Scanner strong = new Scanner(System.in);


while (isNumber(dato) == true && dato.length() != 5){
        System.out.println("Isnt a correct id number");
        strng = strong.nextLine();

    }
```

But with this I can introduce a dot or a semi-colon, I tried with `[a-zA-Z]+` and the `boolean` in false but isn't work I'm searching only for numbers from 0 to 9.

Any clue for this?

Comment: `strng.contains("[0-9]+")` returns `true` for inputs that has digits, but doesn't check that it has *only* digits.

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, it will not. `strng.contains("[0-9]+")` returns `true` only if the string literally contains `[0-9]+`. The `contains` method does not take a regular expression.

Comment: @Jesper You're right. `matches` accepts `CharSequence` and not a regex string. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`strng.contains("[0-9]+")` should rather be `strng.matches("[0-9]+")`

This will test your `strng` to have one or more digits.

If you want your string to match **exactly** five digits, then you'll have to use the `"[0-9]{5}"` pattern.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply! i tried matches too but it only see if the string have a number and not if it hasnt other character so i can introduce "1234." and the string has numbers but the dot isnt good

Comment: It's a good practice to *explicitly* call `Pattern.compile` before passing the regex to `matches`.

Comment: True. Especially for more complex patterns.

Comment: @MathewEuler "*but the dot isnt good*" is that a problem? Based on your title you only wanted "*0-9 and no other characters*".

Comment: Exactly, i only have to be able to 0-9 digits and nothing else, the problem is that with contains or matches ([0-9]+{5}) isnt working

Comment: How about with `"[0-9]{5}"`?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the content *and* the length with your regex:

```
strng.matches("[0-9]{5}")
```

This will return `true` for strings of exactly 5 characters, containing only digit characters.